# NodeJS MongoDB API in Docker Container can't connect to Database running on Host

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have a MongoDB Database set up on my host server and a docker container running on that host with a NodeJS application. In that application, I try to connect to the Database on the host but the request always times out.

I set the network to "host" and used the adress "host.docker.internal". I also tried installing mongodb-shell and it actually works! So basically I can connect to the database with the shell in the container but not with the MongoDB NodeJS API.

Code of the NodeJS application:

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
mongodb.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/");
```

using `mongo mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/` in the shell works and I connect correctly.

Comment: Did you configure mongodb to listen on this interface too? IIRC it's something from 172.0.0.0/8 network, and mongo by default listens only on localhost.

Comment: I don't think I did. The host network from my understanding just means that the containers run like they would run on your PC directly. Also this shouldn't be a issue because it works with the shell which means that it can connect from the container, right?

Comment: You are missing username and password from your URL... "mongodb://user:pass@host.docker.internal:27017/"

Comment: That's interesting. I don't have a mac nearby to reproduce it, but if I did my first step would be to check what tcpdump/wireshark says

Comment: The thing I cannot wrap my head around is how do you even get that timeout? You're not using any callback? The code shown simply have no means to do something when it works, or even when it not works... How do you know it is not working?

Comment: @Salketer 1) it doesn't matter that those information is missing, it just defaults to nothing which is fine since i don't use auth atm. 2) it just throws a uncatched exception and exists with that and that exception shows "ECONNECT Refused: 127.0.0.1" (yes, it's actually that IP and not the one I put in...). I knew that something was wrong because in my actual application which has error handling it didn't work and threw a exception too.

Comment: Okok, that 127.0.0.1 part is the missing piece of the puzzle I think. From the container, if you ping host.docker.internal, you are getting a different URL than that I'm guessing? Could you try to hard code the URL in the javascript, just to test?

Comment: the ping gave back the IP `192.168.65.2` which I then tried to put in as the URL. Unfortunately tho, this doesn't work either. I can ping it directly from the app container but mongodb still doesn't connect...

Comment: Are you sure it is exactly the snippet that gives you the "ECONNECT Refused: 127.0.0.1" error? I know the uncaught async exceptions may not have sufficient call stack, if so , can you confirm it in the interactive nodejs shell? The IP discrepancy makes me thinking something in your app is trying to connect to the db with default "localhost" settings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sounds really promising.
I will try to do that when I'm home, unfortunately I'm currently in school and I will only be able to try it in like 3 hours.

Comment: @AlexBlex tried that now, it still errors with the same URL... Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/zTMgyFO.png

Comment: @Jakob could you double check if you do not try to connect from somewhere else? Because I just tested it myself and the error returned displays the domain name and not the resolved IP. Which means, with the code above, the TopologyDescription would have the domain name passed and not the IP. Here's my error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.12:27017 which is HOST IP, but in topology: servers: Map(1) { 'host.docker.internal:27017' => [ServerDescription] },

Comment: @Jakob, try to reproduce interactive experience on a fresh alpine container. If it is reproducible, please update the question with dockerfile and package.json - there may be an issue with particular version of the driver.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @AlexBlex and Salketer, thanks for the help, I finally fixed it by binding the server to the right IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the issue.
I had to bind it to the correct IPs / in my config I used the argument `--bind_ip_all`.

Thanks a lot for the help!